# Error trying to run agetty in a runit based linux installation

Tags: linux, tty, init-script, runit

I am trying to run agetty in a runit based linux system, but I have the following problem

```
sh: cannot set terminal process group (136) Inappropriate ioctl for device
sh: no job control in this shell
```

I have no clue about this error, do you have some ideas

The script for running agetty is

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /sbin/agetty 38400 tty1 linux --noclear
```

Any help will be good.

Comment: For the same message for the same reason in a different scenario, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410318/ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `setsid` as follows.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec setsid /sbin/agetty 38400 tty1 linux --noclear
```

The `setsid` wrapper will start agetty as a session leader ([see this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18178/94032)), allowing it to bind to `tty1`.

You can see the different behavior from the following example `ps`.

```
# ps xao pid,ppid,sid,tty,cmd
[...]
150 1   150 ?    runsvdir
154 150 155 ?    runsv agetty-3
157 154 157 tty3 -bash
152 150 152 ?    runsv agetty-4
156 152 152 ?    -bash
[...]
```

The `agetty-3` service used `setsid`, whereas `agetty-4` did not. Therefore, the shell on tty3 is session leader and bound to its tty. The shell on tty4 is in the same session of its supervisor and not bound (`?` in tty column).