# Is a session leader the only process in its group?

Tags: linux, shell, process, session

The following diagram from APUE leads me to wonder: in a process session, does the process group of the session leader contain only the session leader and no other process?

- Any process created by `fork()` will inherit the same process group and session from its parent. So can  the session leader     fork arbitrary number of processes into its own process group?
- For example, is a shell (when it is a session leader)  the only process in its process group? If yes, is it because when the shell forks a child process, the child is initially in the same process group as the shell, but then [immediately starts a new process group by calling `setpgid()`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/64447609994bfddeef1061948022c074093e9a9f/jobs.c#L2027) ?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18166/what-are-session-leaders-in-ps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no such restriction. If it was the case, commands that don't implement job control (in practice, only shells do) wouldn't be able to fork a process (as child processes inherit the process group) when started as `xterm -e that-command` for instance.

Even when the session leader is an interactive shell with job control enabled, you can have other processes in its group.

Running:

```
xterm -e 'sleep 1000 & exec zsh'
```

And in that `xterm`:

```
  PID  PGID   SID TTY          TIME CMD
14003 14003 14003 pts/20   00:00:00 zsh
14004 14003 14003 pts/20   00:00:00 sleep
14012 14012 14003 pts/20   00:00:00 ps
```

Most commands run from an interactive shell are run in separate process groups, but it's not the case for all.

For instance, in `bash`:

```
$ exec 3< <(sleep 1000)
$ ps -j
  PID  PGID   SID TTY          TIME CMD
13913 13913 13913 pts/19   00:00:00 bash
14136 13913 13913 pts/19   00:00:00 bash
14137 13913 13913 pts/19   00:00:00 sleep
14138 14138 13913 pts/19   00:00:00 ps
```

Or the processes started as part of prompt expansions:

```
$ PS1=$'$(ps -j)\n$ '
  PID  PGID   SID TTY          TIME CMD
14212 14212 14212 pts/18   00:00:00 bash
14292 14212 14212 pts/18   00:00:00 ps
$
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know why bash makes some child processes into new process groups, but not  some other child processes?

Answer (score 1):

All external commands are run in a process group different from the one of the shell. The shell is a session leader and thus that is the only process in its process group.

All commands which belong to the same pipeline are in the same process group.

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct that `proc1` and `proc2` may run external commands, but why are they  in the same group in the diagram, contradicting to "All external commands are run in a different process group" ?

Comment: @Tim Probably a misunderstanding. I have improved the wording.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my post. Hope that I clarify my problem.