# Processes in a session in an interactive shell vs in a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, ps, command-substitution, session

If I run this command in a script it doesn't produce output except header from the `ps`:

```
 # Taken from Advanced Bash Usage on youtube:

 echo "$(echo "$(echo "$(echo "$(ps wwf -s $$)")")")"
```

This is the output:

```
$./testing.bash
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
```

but here it is run in a terminal which produces the **expected output**:

```
$echo "$(echo "$(echo "$(echo "$(ps wwf -s $$)")")")"
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
18289 pts/4    Ss+    0:00 /bin/bash
17917 pts/4    S+     0:00  \_ /bin/bash
17918 pts/4    S+     0:00      \_ /bin/bash
17919 pts/4    S+     0:00          \_ /bin/bash
17920 pts/4    S+     0:00              \_ /bin/bash
17921 pts/4    R+     0:00                  \_ ps wwf -s 18289
```

**QUESTION:**

**Can you explain the difference and show me the right way to do this?**

I've tried a lot of things and searched google for 4 hours, if you need I can list what I tried but I don't think that's relevant here.

```
$echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

and:

```
$head -1 testing.bash 
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18166/what-are-session-leaders-in-ps

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ps`' `-s sessionid` option is to select processes based on their session id.

You can use `ps -j` to see the session id of processes. Sessions along with process groups are generally used for shell job control (hence the `-j`).

Your terminal emulator creates a new session with the process that it then reuses to execute your preferred shell. So, in a terminal, the session id will generally be the same as the pid of that shell.

So, if you run `ps -j -s "$$"` in **that** shell, you'll get the processes in the session because `"$$"` *happens* to be the same as the session id.

If you run that command in any other shell (like the shell that is executed in a child process to interpret your `testing` script), any shell that is not a session leader, you'll get nothing because there's no session with an id that corresponds to the pid of that shell.

```
$ ps -j -s "$$"
  PID  PGID   SID TTY          TIME CMD
 7239  7239  7239 pts/7    00:00:00 zsh
21002 21002  7239 pts/7    00:00:00 ps
```

`$$` is 7239, the session leader. So that `ps -j -s 7239` gives me all the processes in that session.

```
$ sh -xc 'ps -j -s "$$"; ps -j -p "$$"'
+ ps -j -s 21044
  PID  PGID   SID TTY          TIME CMD
+ ps -j -p 21044
  PID  PGID   SID TTY          TIME CMD
21044 21044  7239 pts/7    00:00:00 sh
```

The first `ps` command returns nothing because, as the second `ps` shows, there's no session with id 21044 as the process of id 21044 is not a session leader. The session leader is still 7239, the shell started by the terminal emulator.

```
$ sh -xc 'ps -j -s "$(($(ps -o sid= -p "$$")))"'
+ ps -o sid= -p 21215
+ ps -j -s 7239
  PID  PGID   SID TTY          TIME CMD
 7239  7239  7239 pts/7    00:00:00 zsh
21215 21215  7239 pts/7    00:00:00 sh
21217 21215  7239 pts/7    00:00:00 ps
```

Now, we see all the processes in the session. We used `ps -o sid= -p "$$"` to get the id of the session that `$$` belongs to.

Comment: So would one possible "right way to do this" be to execute the script with `setsid` e.g. `setsid -w ./testing.bash`?

Comment: @steeldriver, yes that would create a new session with the shell interpreting the script being the session leader. You could also use `script` or `xterm` or any other terminal emulator or run it over ssh that would also create a new session. Or you could use `-G` instead of `-s` to get the processes in the job instead of the session (which would work as long as $$ is the process group leader which would generally be the case if the script is started on its one by an interactive shell)